# Flask/Jinja2 field formatting via macros

Tags: flask, macros, jinja2

So I have a site built in Flask.  To maintain look and feel from page to page, I use macros in Jinja2 to render the fields.  My question is this: how do I take control of field width on a per field basis?  I have several fields that dont render wide enough to display the data that ends up in them.  I know it could be done with CSS, but I want to control just certain fields via the template or forms.py and leave the rest alone.

HTML template example:

```
{% from "_forms.html" import render_field %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {{ render_field(form.createDate) }}
    <br>
    {{ render_field(form.changeID) }}
    <br>
    {{ render_field(form.tasID) }}
    <br>
    {{ render_field(form.implementor) }}
    <br>
    {{ form.submit }}
{% endblock %}
```

Jinja2 macro:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <hr class="forms">
  {{ field.label }}
  {% if field.flags.required %}
    *
  {% endif %}
  <br>
  {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <span class="flash">{{ error }}</span><br>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Examples of what I've tried in the html template:

```
{{ render_field(form.customer, form_type="horizontal", horizontal_columns=('lg', 6, 3)) }}
{{ render_field(form.customer, horizontal_columns=('lg', 2, 6)) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the answer was pretty simple.

```
{{ render_field(form.createDate, size=50) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `input` tag like that `<input type="text" name="email" size="60">` instead of `render_field` Jinja2 method so size attribute changes width of `input`. However, you'll have to make extra changes to make it work with your Flask server.

Would be probably easier to include `CSS` file or just use embedded `CSS`.

Comment: Thats basically the route im using now.  Was hoping to continue using the macros though.  Makes maintaining look and feel across the site much easier.